# React Input losing focus after keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a an app in React/Redux and I have some input fields that lose focus after each key stroke. My code looks like this:

```
<General fields={props.general}
    onChange={value => props.updateValue('general', value)} />

<FormWrapper>
    <Network fields={props.network}
        onChange={value => props.updateValue('network', value} />
    </NetworkTableForm>
</FormWrapper>
```

`General` and `Network` just contain different sections of the form and `FormWrapper` can wrap a subsection of the form and provide some interesting visualisations. The problem is that all of the fields in `General` work fine but the fields in `Network` lose focus after each keystroke. I've already tried appending keys to a bunch of different elements such as `General` `Network`, `FormWrapper` and my components wrapping my input fields and the reason that I'm not using redux-form is because it doesn't work well with the UI framework that I'm using(Grommet). Any idea what could be causing this?

Edit: Adding more code as per request. Here's the full component:

```
const InfoForm = (props) => {

    let FormWrapper = FormWrapperBuilder({
        "configLists": props.configLists,
        "showForm": props.showForm,
        "loadConfiguration": props.loadConfiguration,
        "updateIndex": props.updateIndex,
        "metadata": props.metadata})

    return (
        <CustomForm onSubmit={() => console.log('test')}
             loaded={props.loaded} heading={'System Details'}
             header_data={props.header_data}
             page_name={props.general.name} >

            <General fields={props.general}
                 onChange={(field, value) => props.updateValue('general', field, value)} />

            <FormWrapper labels={["Interface"]} fields={["interface"]} component={'network'}>
                <Network fields={props.network}
                    onChange={(field, value) => props.updateValue('network', field, value)} />
            </FormWrapper>

            <User fields={props.user}
                 onChange={(field, value) => props.updateValue('user', field, value)} />


        </CustomForm>
    )
}

export default InfoForm
```

Here's an example of a form section component:

```
const Network = ({fields, onChange}) => (
    <CustomFormComponent title='Network'>
        <CustomTextInput value={fields.interface} label='Interface'
            onChange={value => onChange('interface', value)} />

        <CustomIPInput value={fields.subnet} label='Subnet'
            onChange={value => onChange('subnet', value)} />

        <CustomIPInput value={fields.network} label='Network'
            onChange={value => onChange('network', value)} />

        <CustomIPInput value={fields.gateway} label='Gateway'
            onChange={value => onChange('gateway', value)} />

        <CustomIPInput value={fields.nat_ip} label='NAT'
            onChange={value => onChange('nat_ip', value)} />
    </CustomFormComponent>
)

export default Network
```

Here's an example of one of the custom inputs:

```
const CustomTextInput = ({label, value, onChange}) => (
    <FormField label={<Label size='small'>{label}</Label>}>
        <Box pad={{'horizontal': 'medium'}}>
            <TextInput placeholder='Please Enter' value={value}
                onDOMChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}
            />
        </Box>
    </FormField>
)

export default CustomTextInput
```

And here's the FormWrapperBuilder function:

```
const FormWrapperBuilder = (props) =>
    ({component, labels, fields, children=undefined}) =>
        <VisualForm
            configLists={props.configLists[component]}
            showForm={visible => props.showForm(component, visible)}
            loadConfiguration={index => props.loadConfiguration(component, index)}
            updateIndex={index => props.updateIndex(component, index)}
            metadata={props.metadata[component]}
            labels={labels} fields={fields} >
            {children}
        </VisualForm>

export default FormWrapperBuilder
```

All of these are kept in separate files which may affect the rerendering of the page and it's the functions that are wrapped in the FormWrapper that lose focues after a state change. Also I've tried adding keys to each of these components without any luck. Also here's the functions in my container component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        'updateValue': (component, field, value) => {
            dispatch(updateValue(component, field, value))},

        'showForm': (component, visible) => {
            dispatch(showForm(component, visible))
        },

        'loadConfiguration': (component, index) => {
            dispatch(loadConfiguration(component, index))
        },

        'pushConfiguration': (component) => {
            dispatch(pushConfiguration(component))
        },

        'updateIndex': (component, index) => {
            dispatch(updateIndex(component, index))
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Modified my custom text input as such as per Hadas' answer. Also slathered it with keys and refs for good measure

```
export default class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {value: ""}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FormField key={this.props.label} ref={this.props.label} label={<Label size='small'>{this.props.label}</Label>}>
                <Box key={this.props.label} ref={this.props.label} pad={{'horizontal': 'medium'}}>
                    <TextInput placeholder='Please Enter' value={this.state.value} key={this.props.label} ref={this.props.label}
                    onDOMChange={event => { this.props.onChange(event.target.value); this.state.value = event.target.value }} />
                </Box>
            </FormField>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your updatevalue function, seems like the key to the answer

Comment: Sure, do you mean the function in the reducer or in the container?

Comment: Perhaps edit your question so its easily visible

Comment: Sure, I'd add some more code now

Comment: Requested information added.

Answer (score 1):

React is re-rendering the DOM on each key stroke. Try setting value to a variable attached to the component's state like this:

`<TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    value={this.state.text}></TextInput`

Comment: Is it still the exact same problem? Losing focus after a key stroke? Or any other info you can give about the changes?

Comment: Sorry should have said - this issue is now that I cant enter input with this updated version which makes sense because it seems to me that state.value gets set to the empty string on every state change(which is every keystroke in the case of this component). In terms of all of my changes that's really all there is. I've been adding and removing keys and refs on components all day and changing components from stateless to stateful in the hopes that something would work but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: I've also been trying to tickle the `shouldComponentUpdate()` and `componentWillMount()` lifecycle methods to stop the component from updating on state change to no avail. I think the issue is probably in the `FormWrapperBuilder` (Because its the component wrapped `FormWrapper`  that loses focus)

Comment: take out the ref's and key's. That could mess it up if not implemented properly. also use onChangeText instead of onDOMChange. I tested the snippet that I just edited the answer to and it worked